# TSlint not dealing with React Native Redux components correctly

Tags: react-native, react-redux, webstorm, tslint

Let's say I have this

```
interface IProps {
  text: string
}

class TextComponent extends PureComponent<IProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: ITextComponentReduxStore) {
  return {
    text: state.text,
  }
}

function dispatchAction(dispatch: (x: any) => any) {
  return {
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchAction)(TextComponent)
```

When I want to use this component, I simply do

```
<TextComponent />
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     <- Webstorm underlines this
```

Webstorm (TSLint) complains about

```
TS2741: Property 'text' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<Pick<IProps, "text">>'.
```

How can I prevent this?

The props is part of Redux store

Answer (score 0):

you define props as required

```
interface IProps {
  text: string
}
```

So you need to use component

```
<TextComponent text={“...”}/>
```

or you define it as optional

```
interface IProps {
  text?: string
}
```

so you can use it as

```
<TextComponent/>
```

if you want to pass a complex object as a prop

```
interface IProps {
  data?: ProfileData[];
}
```

and ProfileData interface,

```
interface ProfileData {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    photos: string[];
}
```

and you can use your component

```
<TextComponent data={[{name:”John”, age:26, photos:[“url1”,”url2”]}]}/>
```

or if you don’t want to define a specific type, you can just define it as `any`

```
interface IProps {
  data?: any;
}
```

but it is not a good choice with typescript.

Comment: hum.. what if I have a complex object instead of just a `string` as a prop? Isn't there a way to tell tslint to just not consider `IProps`?